# How many tests followed for patients with suspected category only in, R

Tags: r, count, duplicates, tidyverse

I have  reproducible example. I have duplicate ids. Some are suspected some not.

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), test = c("susp", 
"susp", "neg", "pos", "pos", "neg", "pos", "susp", "susp", "neg"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Yet, I am interested to get the counts:

1. A total count of suspected patients
2. of those clients that are suspected that followed multiple testing regardless of the outcome.
3. want to get a total count of those with two and three suspected.

CAVEATS !! If this could be done with tidyverse, that would be amazing.
a sample of how the table should look like, see bellow.

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 4), number_of_test_for_suspected_pat = c(2, 
2)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

And additional tibble with a total of suspected patients with subsequent tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `filter` output the 'id's that doesn't have any 'susp'ected cases and then get the `sum` of logical `vector

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter('susp' %in% test) %>% 
    summarise(number_of_test_for_suspected_pat = sum(test == 'susp'),
    n_greater_than_3 = number_of_test_for_suspected_pat >=3) %>%
     mutate(Total = sum(number_of_test_for_suspected_pat), 
         n_greater_than_3_count = sum(n_greater_than_3))
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#     id number_of_test_for_suspected_pat n_greater_than_3 Total n_greater_than_3_count
#  <dbl>                            <int> <lgl>            <int>                  #<int>
#1     1                                2 FALSE                4                      0
#2     4                                2 FALSE                4                      0
```

---

Or do the `filter` first

```
df1 %>%
   filter(test == 'susp') %>%
   count(id) %>%
   mutate(Total = sum(n))
```

Comment: thank you akrun. it works well!! Yet, forgot to mention want a total of those as well. Total being 4. Will then go back and rephrase my question

Comment: @GaB I don't know.  I don't use github that much

Comment: I may need to rephrase the question. Apologies.

Comment: @GaB can you please post as a new question if it is more changes

Comment: I actually want to do something very similar. I want to get a count of those with more than 1,2,3 suspected. Shall I then psot another question, since it is pretty simmilar?

Comment: @GaB Here, in this case, there is only 2 suspects.  If you want more then, use `n_greater_than3 = sum(sum(test == 'susp') > 3)`